# How to implement events in solidity

Tags: solidity, events

I have an error whenever I add the event line
for EVM logging and to notify anyone listening that this transfer took place.

```
function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns (bool sufficient) {     //receiver 160 bit public address of receipient 
                                                                                     //amount # of coins to be sent

            if (balances[msg.sender] < amount || balances[receiver] + amount < balances[receiver]) throw;             //Check current balance of msg.sender is less than amount to send if yes, then dont execute 

            balances[msg.sender] -= amount;         

                 //If msg.sender is greater than amount then subtract the # of coins from sender account
        balances[receiver] += amount;                                           // and add the # of coins to receiver account
        return true;

    //event sendCoin(address indexed sender, address indexed receiver, uint256 amount); 
    //sendCoin(msg.sender, receiver, amount)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Events are convenience interfaces with the EVM logging facilities.

#### Define an Event

```
event HighestBidIncreased(address bidder, uint amount); // Event
```

#### Triggering an Event

```
emit HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value); // Triggering event using emit
```

You can avoid the `params` if you don't want them.

[source](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/structure-of-a-contract.html?highlight=event#events)

Comment: Compilers above ^0.4.21 needs `emit`  keyword to call the `event`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that fixes the question:

```
contract C {
    event EventSendCoin(address indexed sender, address indexed receiver, uint256 amount);

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns (bool sufficient) {
        // ...
        EventSendCoin(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Some things to note:

- events are declared outside of the function
- event names must be different from function names
- event names are CapWords per Solidity styleguide
- an event name that is more than 1 character/case different than a function name leads to less confusion