# Web Server Listen For When ERC20 Token Transferred

Tags: erc-20

Is it possible to have a web server listen or know when a transfer has been made on a particular ERC20 Token Contract?

From what I researched, we are not able to make a HTTP request inside the contract's transfer method.

Is there some way for an external web server to "watch" the blockchain for when those custom tokens are transferred?

Thanks

Comment: This is possible using javascript web3js and events

Comment: Are you able to explain more? Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [token tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/token), at the end of the `transfer` method the following code is executed:

```
/* Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place */
Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
```

This emits an [Event](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11228/what-is-an-event).

You can 'listen' for emitted Events using [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents) for example.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct.