# Getting notified after receiving tokens

Tags: transactions, ether, tokens, myetherwallet

Is there any way to get a notification(PN, Email etc.) when one receives ETH or tokens issued on ethereum?

Comment: Can you please specify your question a little bit and give an example of the contract you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the notification system on etherscan.io:

1. Create an account on https://etherscan.io and/or log in
2. Go to https://etherscan.io/myaddress
3. Click `Add New Address`
4. Enter the address you want to track
5. Select `Email Notification`
6. Click `Continue`

You should now receive email notifications.

Please note that there is a limit of 100 emails/day.

Comment: it doesn't notify you if you want token transfers

Answer (score 3):

[Cryptocurrency Alerting](https://cryptocurrencyalerting.com/wallet-watch.html) does exactly this.  You can monitor any ETH address and get alerted when your ETH/ERC-20 token balance changes.  It works well for airdrops, for example.

You can receive alerts via Email, Webhook, SMS, Slack, Telegram, Discord and several other options.  Disclaimer: I am friends with the owner of this site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dagger https://matic.network/dagger to send email/notification when -

- you receive tokens
- someone transfers tokens/ETH from the multi-sig wallet
- ....or track any contract

Here is the simple example of how to watch ERC20 token transfer using Dagger:

```
// web3 contract
var web3Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

// dagger contract
var contract = dagger.contract(web3Contract);
var filter = contract.events.Transfer({filter: {from: '0x123456...'}, room: 'latest'});

// watch
filter.watch(function(data, removed){
    // data.returnValues.to : address to which it has been transferred to
    // data.returnValues.value : value which has been transferred
});

// watch only once
filter.watchOnce(function(data, removed){
    // data.returnValues.to : address to which it has been transferred to
    // data.returnValues.value : value which has been transferred
});

// stop watching
filter.stopWatching();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use events in the smart contract which receives the the ETH or Tokens. When the function in the contract, which will receive the ETH or tokens, will be called an event can be triggerd with return values such as PN and Email etc. You could catch this events in your Dapp. See [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11228/what-is-an-event) for more information on events.

Comment: @niksmac your edit seems to make this answer rather unintelligible?

Comment: This is more generic approach, but have you designed any code for that yet? It seems quite interesting though.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Sorry, that looks like an accident. Reverted.