# How do I get the transaction hash and boolean return value?

Tags: solidity, web3js, address.transfer

I'm making a simple time-lock contract in Solidity. In my funds withdraw function I have:

```
function withdraw_funds() public returns (bool) {
        if (getAccounts[msg.sender].amount > 0) {

            if(getAccounts[msg.sender].releasetime < now){
            msg.sender.transfer(getAccounts[msg.sender].amount);
            return (true);
        }}
        else {
            return(false);
        }
     }
```

On the front end I'm using:

```
SimpleContract.withdraw_funds(function(err,result){
                if(!err){
                    console.log(result);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Failure");
                }
            });
```

With the above function I get the transaction hash regardless of whether the funds were actually transferred or not.

Could someone please tell me the correct way to check the Boolean return value and display the transaction hash if the transfer was successful ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `return(false)` you can use `revert()` or maybe use `events` so on frontend you can have listeners to be triggered by each event.

I suggest read these:

- [Error handling: Assert, Require, Revert and Exceptions](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)
- [What is an Event?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11228/what-is-an-event)
- [Solidity Events Tutorial - Using Web3.js to Listen for Smart Contract Events](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/100/Solidity-Events-Tutorial---Using-Web3.js-to-Listen-for-Smart-Contract-Events)