# Understanding what events are doing in Solidity

Tags: solidity, tokens, events

**CONTEXT OF THE QUESTION:**

The references at the end of this post gave me the following understanding of events:

> Whenever a transaction takes place that is meant to alter information
>   in the blockchain, an event is the tool used to do the logging of that
>   information.

Since I am coding my first **ERC-20 Standard compatible Token**, here is an example of the usage of events:

```
mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) 
{
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
    balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
    Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

- *source: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard*

The second line declares an event that has 3 input variables, who is sending (**from**), who is receiving (**to**), and the amount being sent (**tokens**). And when the function `transfer` is involved we see the usage of the event. It makes sense to me that this is where it should be involved, but what I don't understand is how Solidity ties this code:

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
```

with making sure that the `balances` of users are not faked. The event in my mind must be linking the 3 parameters together into the blockchain, but how does that linking happen? and how does the blockchain then prevent `balances` from being faked.

**DETAILED QUESTIONS:**

- What happens behind the scenes that links the `Transfer` event with the verification of what the balances are? Please feel free to go into depths
- If I had used another word, like `Foobar` and replaced the word `Transfer` with it, would the code still work? The reason I ask is because it seems like I am defining what `Transfer` is doing by declaring it (so by default it not being a predefined event of solidity), but I don't seem to be coding in much else.

---

References:

- [What is an Event?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11228/what-is-an-event)
- http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#events

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An event is basically a print statement by the contract. Nothing is verified. The contract can log whatever it wants.

> What happens behind the scenes that links the Transfer event with the verification of what the balances are? Please feel free to go into depths

Absolutely nothing.

> If I had used another word, like Foobar and replaced the word Transfer with it, would the code still work? The reason I ask is because it seems like I am defining what Transfer is doing by declaring it (so by default it not being a predefined event of solidity), but I don't seem to be coding in much else.

Yes, but someone reading the event would see an event called "Foobar" instead.

Comment: Oh so events have nothing to do with how ethereum enforces byzantine fault tolerance? They are just a type of `console.log(...)` for practicality purposes?

Comment: That's correct.